# Command Block conditionals - doesn't work with quotation marks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help with this command:

`/setblock 262 73 -253 command_block[facing=east,conditional=false]{Command:"/execute if block 258 73 -254 chest{Items:[{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook"}]}"} replace`

Could someone fix this for me?
I have tried for hours and can't get it to work. It's supposed to place a command block with the command `/execute if block 258 73 -254 chest{Items:[{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook"}]}`, but it just won't work. It needs to be facing east, with its conditional set to false. I did that, but it still won't work.

Note: my Minecraft version is 1.14.2

Comment: What part is failing?  I have a good idea of some of the problems, and there are multiple, but it helps everyone if you describe in more detail how things aren't working.

Comment: The Part That Is Failing Is The "minecraft:tripwire_hook"}]}"} It Doesn't Seem To Like "

Comment: Msg Me Back If You See The Message @Virusbomb

Comment: I can't help with any Minecraft commands. I'm just a user here and help with reviewing and editing and cleaned up your question so it was more direct and the commands were easier to read.

Comment: Escaping. You have quotation marks inside quotation marks, replace them with `\"`.

Comment: ok thanks! I will see if that works!

Comment: @FabianRöling please, post your comment as answer

Comment: @arghtype Only if the asker says that it works, because I've not actually checked anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You can´t have quotation marks within quotation marks, the game thinks that you have two text strings and some text in between.

You can use `'` instead of the outer quotation mark, or you can mark a quotation mark as part of a string by using `\`

So either of these would work:

```
/setblock 262 73 -253 command_block[facing=east,conditional=false]{Command:'/execute if block 258 73 -254 chest{Items:[{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook"}]}'} replace
/setblock 262 73 -253 command_block[facing=east,conditional=false]{Command:"/execute if block 258 73 -254 chest{Items:[{id:\"minecraft:tripwire_hook\"}]}"} replace
```

The easiest way to get a complex `/setblock` command that works propperly is to create the block that you want to set and then to look at it and press F3+I. This will put a setblock command into your clipboard, that you can paste in with Ctrl+V:

```
/setblock 262 73 -253 minecraft:command_block[conditional=false,facing=east]{auto:0b,powered:0b,LastExecution:1497985L,SuccessCount:1,UpdateLastExecution:1b,conditionMet:1b,CustomName:'{"text":"@"}',Command:'/execute if block 258 73 -254 chest{Items:[{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook"}]}',LastOutput:'{"extra":[{"translate":"commands.execute.conditional.pass"}],"text":"[16:14:24] "}',TrackOutput:1b}
```

You can then remove the parts that are unimportant for your situation, to make the command shorter:

```
/setblock 262 73 -253 minecraft:command_block[conditional=false,facing=east]{Command:'/execute if block 258 73 -254 chest{Items:[{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook"}]}'}
```

I suggest doing that in a text editor, as it is easier to format text there and the minecraft chat line is limited and cuts the end of the command. A command block is limited, too, but the limit is much higher. It is still not optimal for editing long commands though.

This works for creating `/summon` commands, too, simply look at an entity instead.